why are geodesics invariant under isometries?
I am reading Do Carmo "Geometry of Curves and Surfaces" and in section 4.4 (Parallel transport. Geodesics) in Example 4 Do Carmo claims without proof that geodesics are invariant under isometries. How do we prove this?
If $F:S_1 \to S_2$ is an isometry and $\gamma$ is a geodesic in $S_1$ we have that
$$\frac{D\gamma'}{dt}(t)=0$$
and I wish to prove that
$$\frac{D(F \circ \gamma)'(t)}{dt}=0$$
The maximum I can get is the following:
$$\langle dF_{\gamma(t)}.\gamma'(t),dF_{\gamma(t)}.\gamma'(t)\rangle=\langle \gamma'(t),\gamma'(t) \rangle $$
so we can apply Covariant derivative in both sides to achieve
$$2\langle\frac{D}{dt}dF_{\gamma(t)}.\gamma'(t),dF_{\gamma(t)}.\gamma'(t) \rangle=0.$$
how do we conclude from here?
Please I want help only with the theory developed in Do Carmo "Curves and Surfaces" book and I don't wish to use more general theories like Riemannian Geometry.

The most straightforward answer to your question at that point in DoCarmo is to note that geodesics are solutions of a system of differential equations (with Christoffel symbols appearing as the coefficients). Since the first fundamental form is — by definition — preserved by a (local) isometry, so will be the Christoffel symbols (because they are given in terms of the first fundamental form and its derivatives).
Thinking of the covariant derivative in terms of its extrinsic definition will not be helpful. To relate the covariant derivative with isometries more abstractly, you're probably going to need to think about parallel translation along curves and how (local) isometries preserve that.

Do Carmo casually claims that because it is almost a tautology.
Defining geodesics : [...] a geodesic is a curve representing in some sense the shortest path (arc) between two points in a surface [...]
Defining isometries : [...] distance-preserving transformation between metric spaces [...]
Hence when we have various distances between various points (according to our metric) where we mark out a geodesic (with shortest distance) to then apply the given isometry (preserving distances) , then the transformation will still give some new geodesic (new shortest distance) according to those definitions themselves to finish it off.

Or, shortly: extrema of arc length are invariant under isometries because they are mapped to extrema of arc length.

Thank you for the help, I can understand the intuitive reasoning behind the statement.But how to prove this formally? that the covariant derivative is zero ?

I think this is formal too , though you might want "calculations" , then we apply Chain Rule to $[F(\gamma(t))]'$ which will work out to $F'(\gamma(t)) \times \gamma'(t)$ where we know that $\gamma'(t)=0$.

But following the definition given at Do Carmo $\gamma'(t)$ is not necessarily $0$. The definition says that $\frac{D\gamma'}{dt}(t)=0$ where $D$ is the covariant derivative.

I will get back to you on that , @Victor , though that might take a little while.

Actually, a local isometry is not defined the way you think it is. The metric space structure has yet to be defined. And I’m sad to say that your subsequent comment is totally incorrect.

Oh , no worries ! I agree with that assessment , @TedShifrin , Is there something salvageable in this answer ? Should I just delete that ?
